# Is there a way to never ever have a scroll bar on a div?

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I have a div that, depending on circumstances, can overflow. Is there a way so that, no matter how much data is in the div, it will **not** have a scroll bar? I was hoping that there would be a style I could just add like:

`<div style="width:100; height:100; noscroll:true" >`

Is there such a thing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use `overflow: hidden;` and it will never show a scroll bar. Note that this might also disable scrolling (even with mouse wheel) in some browsers.

You can specify `overflow-x: hidden;` for horizontal or `overflow-y: hidden;` for vertical scrollbars.