# How can I stop all vertical scrolling on my page?

Tags: html, css

I would like my site to only allow side scrolling (since it's an side scrolling site). Currently on mobile you can scroll endlessly vertically. How is this/

Here's my HTML:

```
<body> 
    <div id="first" class="panel"> <img class="brand" src="assets/images/RF_Logo.png"> </div> 
    <div id="newsletter" class="panel"> ... </div> 
    <div id="directions" class="panel"> ... </div> 
    <div id="contact" class="panel"> ... </div> </div> 
</body>
```

and my CSS:

```
*{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
}
html{
        overflow-y: hidden;
}
body{
    background-color: #1A1A1E;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

.brand{
    width: 300px;
    padding: 10px;
}

#first{
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to never ever have a scroll bar on a div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23683295/is-there-a-way-to-never-ever-have-a-scroll-bar-on-a-div)

Comment: Try adding this into your <head> tags: <meta name=viewport content='user-scalable=no'>

Comment: Works fine for me. Are you doing this on a mac?

Comment: @Trevor Clarke Not great for mobile displays

Comment: @Ashwin No, a Windows 10 PC with Google F12 Mode

Comment: @JackSewell have you tried it?

Comment: @Trevor Clarke Yeah I have.

Answer (score 0):

Add the overflow hidden to the body too in your CSS:

body {
`overflow-y: hidden;`
}

Answer (score 0):

As a starting point you need `height: 100%` and `overflow-y: hidden;` for both `body` and `html` (also *not* `min-height`).